# Using Java's JDBC PreparedStatement on a SQLite Database to query for NOT NULL

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, null, prepared-statement

I'm new to PreparedStatement in Java, and I can't seem to figure out an optimal solution to my problem.  I want to query for records in a table that are either NULL, or NOT NULL.

When reading [PreparedStatement (Java Platform SE 6)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), I realized that I needed to use the [setNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull%28int,%20int%29) method, but I did not see a way to set NOT NULL?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IS NULL
```

What I assume I would do is:

```
public void query(boolean getNull) {
    String querySql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IS ?";
    sqlStatement = connection.prepareStatement(querySql);
    if(getNull)
        sqlStatement.setNull(1, Types.VARCHAR);
    else
        ???;
}
```

But how would I do the else statement?  There is not a setNotNull method.  I assume I could do this:

```
public void query(boolean getNull) {
    String querySql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IS ? NULL";
    sqlStatement = connection.prepareStatement(querySql);
    sqlStatement.setString(1, (getNull ? "" : "NOT"));
}
```

But that seems very 'hackish.'  Is there any better way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Could you describe what you are actually trying to achieve (eg give some sample data and the result you want to get).

Answer (score 1):

? is for passing paramters, not building a SQL. ([taken partially from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246359/sql-prepared-statement-not-taking-on-both-sides-of-where-clause))

I suggest you to use parameters only for values, not fields or `[IS] NULL` (anything like that).

Just concatenate the Strings. If you has more than one parameter you should take a look at [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

```
public void query(boolean getNull) {
    String querySql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IS ";
    if(getNull) {
        querySql += "NULL";
    } else {
        querySql += "NOT NULL";
    }      
    sqlStatement = connection.prepareStatement(querySql);
}
```

also a possible way can be using [`String.format(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), as example:

```
public void query(boolean getNull) {
    String querySql = String.format("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IS %s NULL", (getNull ? "" : "NOT")); 
    sqlStatement = connection.prepareStatement(querySql);
}
```

Comment: I understand.  The main reason I was asking was I was trying to make a single statement that would return either a certain value or all the values using a single query, depending if that value was null or not, but it looks like changing the query is what I'll have to do

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to look at the resultset that is returned by the query:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IS ?"
```

Use your PreparedStatement to set the value to NULL and then execute the query. You can use the `resultset.next()` to test out what you're looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't that just return a resultset of records that have a NULL value in that column?

Comment: @TachisAlopex: Yip that would. So your check would need be put accordingly. If you're expecting your column to be not NULL and your resultset is not empty, then you know your check failed.

Comment: My goal is to get all the values that are not null in a column of values that may or may not be null.  I'm still confused (sorry)

Comment: I'd guess that this actually wouldn't work with most drivers.